# iOS Landscape and Portrait orientation with sibling subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, autolayout

How can I achieve the desired output as per the below screen shots. 
Just to let you know I am not comfortable to `size classes` and `stack views` but has little knowledge on `Autolayout`. 
[image]
[image]

Please let me know can I achieve that only with autolayout ?

I have an idea to add `horizontally center constraints` and removing `vertically center constraints`  in landscape mode, and vice versa in portrait mode when orientation changes with delegate method. `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`

I will post further information if required.

Answer (score 1):

Center your stackview.  When the orientation changes change the [UIStackView.axis](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview/1616223-axis) to either .verticle or .horizontal

Comment: This is the easiest way. Do it in `viewWillTransitionToSize`.